# Python-telegram-bot issue

Tags: python, django, heroku, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have deployed a telegram bot (with Django) on Heroku with python version 3.6.9
It worked well without any issues.
After months I did some changes and while trying to deploy it again I get issues.
Heroku doesn't support python 3.6.9 anymore. It supports 3.6.10
So I set up venv with python 3.6.10 and I'm still getting the same issue after running the server.
Short issue:

```
    from .callbackcontext import CallbackContext File 
"/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/callbackcontext.py"
, line 21, in <module> from telegram import Update 
ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram'
```

(/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/**init**.py)

Also I have tried python 3.7.6 (it's also supported by Heroku) but I get the same issue after running the server:

```
_python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 337, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/init.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
mod = import_module(mod_path)
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 728, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_telegrambot/apps.py", line 9, in
from telegram.ext import Dispatcher
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/init.py", line 25, in
from .callbackcontext import CallbackContext
File "/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/callbackcontext.py", line 21, in
from telegram import Update
ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram' (/home/usr/bot-name/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/init.py)
```

Here you can find my requirements :

```
cffi==1.13.2
cryptography==2.8
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.7
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-telegrambot==1.0.1
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
jdcal==1.4.1
mysqlclient==1.4.5
openpyxl==3.0.2
pipenv==2018.11.26
psycopg2==2.8.4
pycparser==2.19
python-telegram-bot==12.2.0
pytz==2019.3
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
telegram==0.0.1
tornado==6.0.3
virtualenv==16.7.9
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

Comment: As you are trying this after months, you may have to look into `python-telegram-bot` library which also have made many changes in these months

Comment: do you have an app with telegram name now ? if yes you have to rename it to another name

Answer (score 0):

As @GaganTK states, this is most likely due to recent updates in the `python-telegram-bot` library.

I would advise you to check your code conforms to everyting in the [v12 transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in installed packages
After creating a venv with the lastest python version I removed all addition packages from requirements.txt (leaving only Django, python-telegram-bot....) and I removed the freezed version

After I was getting **psycopg error**

Solution was to install some package:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

After I installed requirements without any problems and Django was running well

> Hope I helped someone with this solution

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happen because you are installing `python-telegram-bot==12.2.0` before `telegram==0.0.1`

To solve this issue you must change the position of telegram in `requirementst.txt` file. You first install telegram and after you install python-telegram-bot. Therefore your `requirements.txt` must be like this:

```
cffi==1.13.2
cryptography==2.8
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.7
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-telegrambot==1.0.1
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
jdcal==1.4.1
mysqlclient==1.4.5
openpyxl==3.0.2
pipenv==2018.11.26
psycopg2==2.8.4
pycparser==2.19
telegram==0.0.1
python-telegram-bot==12.2.0
pytz==2019.3
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
tornado==6.0.3
virtualenv==16.7.9
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

This will solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to uninstall both the python-telegram-bot and telegram packages and install only the python-telegram-bot package

```
pip uninstall python-telegram-bot telegram
pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade
```